# SwiftUI - Persist array after View updates

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI, and I think what I'm trying to do is fairly simple, but I just can't see to figure it out.

I have an array of values that I'm using in my app.  I need to save the previous version of that array and, depending on a boolean, overlay the new version of the array with the previous version after the View updates.  I've defined the previous array as a @State variable (maybe that's part of the problem?), but even though I successfully move the current values into previous, when the View updates, the previous array is re-initialized.

Here's the definition of my previous array:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var prevDifferenceLocs = [String]()
    
    private var differenceLocs = [String]()
```

I use this SetPlan method to populate the current array:

```
var body: some View {
        
        var (differencLocs) = setPlan(level: 1, keepSameArray: true, previousDifferences: prevDifferenceLocs)
        
        var prevDifferenceLocs = differenceLocs
```

Then in my setPlan method, I check the boolean to see if we want to use the previous values

```
func setPlan(level:Int, keepSameArray: Bool, previousDifferences: [String]) -> ([String]) {
var locationsOfDifferences = [String]()
if keepSameArray {
            locationsOfDifferences = previousDifferences
        }
```

But every time I get here, previousDifferences is reset.

I think what I need is a way to define prevDifferenceLocs that won't reset when the View updates....

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: Don't do data changes in the `body` of the view, since you don't control View's lifecycle (the view can be recreated due to various reasons, and because it's a struct, it won't keep your changes). There are many ways to manage data in the app. I recommend understanding [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app) page for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting with SwiftUI it is best to try not to worry about view updates at all. Your state (`@State`) should drive the view updates, not the other way around. Like mentioned in the comments you should never change your data (state) in the body of a view. Expect to have no control on when the view is created or updated. It is a bit tricky to understand what you are trying to accomplish here, but maybe this is a step in the right direction:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // even though `prevDifferenceLocs` does not directly drive
    // the UI, you still want this value to be preserved, hence
    // the @State property wrapper
    @State private var prevDifferenceLocs: [String] = []
    @State private var differenceLocs: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // WARNING: this assumes the strings are unique
            // use real identifiable values for production!
            ForEach(differenceLocs, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Button("reset", action: reset)
                Spacer()
                Button("set new plan", action: setNewPlan)
            }
        }   .task {
                // You can load the initial values here
                // (or set the state variables directly)
                setNewPlan()
            }
            .padding()
    }
    
    // restore the previous plan
    func reset() {
        differenceLocs = prevDifferenceLocs
    }
    
    let sample1 = ["123", "456", "789"]
    let sample2 = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
    let sample3 = ["what", "is", "a", "difference", "loc"]
    func setNewPlan() {
        // store the previous plan
        prevDifferenceLocs = differenceLocs

        // set a random new plan
        if let sample = [sample1, sample2, sample3].randomElement() {
            differenceLocs = sample
        }
    }
}
```